# How can I search for an expression that only appear in a full word

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I want to create a search condition in javascript (regex?) that do the following thing:

on this text:

```
I want to know better how#to do.expressions
```

I want that if I search for the letter 't' I will not get any matching result. **only if I search for whole words like "to" or "better" etc I will get a match**. My definition for full words is for spaces and any other characters like "#" ":" "." etc... (so also words like 'how' and 'do' and 'expressions' will match)

assuming that my input field for the text is `str` and I write the code like this:

```
str = "to";
regexp = new RegExp(str, 'g');
match = regexp.exec(string);
```

how should I write it to match my condition (only full words will be selected)

Answer (score 3):

Use `\b` to match word boundaries. For example:

```
> var input = 'I want to know better how#to do.expressions';
  var re = /\bto\b/gi;
  var match = re.exec(input);
> match
  ["to"]
```

Now, since you're building the regex dynamically, you should [quote the input text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript):

```
var input = 'I want to know better how#to do.expressions';
var re = new RegExp('\b' + RegExp.quote(str) + '\b', 'gi');
var match = re.exec(input);
```

Comment: it looks great. your first example works fine. but the second example keeps sending me error that Regexp is not defined and if I change that to RegExp then - javascript doesn't know what is quate. any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @Alon sorry, you're right. It should be `RegExp`, not `Regexp`. Now, if you'd read the question I linked, you'd see the **exact** solution to the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

This will collect all the words consisting of at least 2 characters:

```
string.match(/\w{2,}/g);
```

P.S. It was a pain to understand your question.